# Change Button Color onPress (toggle functionality) React Native

Tags: javascript, user-interface, button, react-native

hope all is well.

I seem to be having difficulty with a basic button functionality. All I need is the state of the class to change and the button style to change every-time the button is pressed. Unlike TouchableHighlight, I need to color change to stay until the button is pressed again (to go back to the original color).

I have tried to use SwitchIOS but it doesn't seem to be easily styled into a circular button, and therefore doesn't really work out. I am a novice so still learning and would greatly appreciate your help. Here is what I have so far:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');
var window = Dimensions.get('window');
var Icon = require('react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  NavigatorIOS,
  Image, 
  TouchableHighlight,
  TextInput,
} = React;


class LS1 extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      paleo: false, 
      vegan: false, 
      vegetarian: false, 
      nutfree: false, 
      dairyfree: false, 
      healthy: false,
      glutenfree: false,
    }
  }

  SkipLogin() {
    var num = window.height/8.335;
    console.log(num);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={require('image!LS1')} style={styles.bgImage}>
          <Text style={styles.icontext}>Help us get to know your dietary lifestyle.</Text>

          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'row',justifyContent: 'center',marginTop:-20}}>
              <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='rgba(73,182,77,1,0.9)' style={styles.bubblechoice}>
                  <Image style={styles.bubblechoice} source={require('image!vegan')}>
                    <View style={styles.overlay}>
                      <Text style={styles.choicetext}>Vegan</Text>
                    </View>
                  </Image>
              </TouchableHighlight>
              <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='rgba(73,182,77,1,0.6)' style={styles.bubblechoice} >
                <Image style={styles.bubblechoice} source={require('image!paleo')}>
                  <View style={styles.overlay}>
                    <Text style={styles.choicetext}>Paleo</Text>
                  </View>
                </Image>
              </TouchableHighlight>
              <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='rgba(73,182,77,1,0.6)' style={styles.bubblechoice} >
                <Image style={styles.bubblechoice} source={require('image!nutfree')}>
                  <View style={styles.overlay}>
                    <Text style={styles.choicetext}>Nut-Free</Text>
                  </View>
                </Image>
              </TouchableHighlight>
              <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='rgba(73,182,77,1,0.6)' style={styles.bubblechoice} >
                <Image style={styles.bubblechoice} source={require('image!glutenfree')}>
                  <View style={styles.overlay}>
                    <Text style={styles.choicetext}>Gluten-Free</Text>
                  </View>
                </Image>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>

            <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'row',justifyContent: 'center',marginTop:-50}}>
              <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='rgba(73,182,77,1,0.6)' style={styles.bubblechoice} >
                <Image style={styles.bubblechoice} source={require('image!dairyfree')}>
                  <View style={styles.overlay}>
                    <Text style={styles.choicetext}>Dairy-Free</Text>
                  </View>
                </Image>
              </TouchableHighlight>
              <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='rgba(73,182,77,1,0.6)' style={styles.bubblechoice} >
                <Image style={styles.bubblechoice} source={require('image!vegetarian')}>
                  <View style={styles.overlay}>
                    <Text style={styles.choicetext}>Vegetarian</Text>
                  </View>
                </Image>
              </TouchableHighlight>
              <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='rgba(73,182,77,1,1)' style={styles.bubblechoice} >
                <Image style={styles.bubblechoice} source={require('image!healthy')}>
                  <View style={styles.overlay}>
                    <Text style={styles.choicetext}>Healthy</Text>
                  </View>
                </Image>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
          </View>

          <Image source={require('image!nextbtn')} style={{resizeMode: 'contain', width:200, height:50, alignSelf: 'center', marginBottom: 50}}/>

          <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.SkipLogin.bind(this)} underlayColor='transparent'>
            <View style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent', alignItems: 'center', marginBottom: 8}}>
              <Text>skip this step</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>

        </Image>
      </View>
    );
  }
};

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
  bgImage: {
    flex: 1,
    width: window.width,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  },
  icontext: {
    color: '#5d5d5d',
    fontWeight: '400',
    fontSize: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    paddingLeft: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: window.height/2.2,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  bubblechoice_click: {
    height: window.height/8.335,
    borderRadius: (window.height/8.3350)/2,
    marginRight: 2,
    width: window.height/8.335,
  },
  bubblechoice: {
    height: window.height/8.335,
    borderRadius: (window.height/8.3350)/2,
    marginRight: 2,
    width: window.height/8.335,
  },
  row: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: -30,
  },
  choicetext: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: 'white',
    marginTop: 35,
    fontWeight: '600',
    marginLeft: -18,
    fontSize: 14,
    flex: 1,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  overlay: {
    backgroundColor:'rgba(80,94,104,0.7)',
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    alignItems:'center'
  },

});

module.exports = LS1;
```

And here is a visual of what that produces:

[image: Frame when all buttons are un-pressed]

Here's what the button should look like after being selected:

[image: Frame when button is pressed]

Comment: Unrelated : Looks like a cool project! :D

Comment: @Trip thanks! It's really coming along - check out the alpha here: https://vimeo.com/202845865

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you should take a step back and do some basic React tutorials before digging too much into React Native - this is a fairly straightforward problem to solve :) Here's a solution for you:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');
var window = Dimensions.get('window');

var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  NavigatorIOS,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TextInput,
} = React;

class ToggleButton extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='rgba(73,182,77,1,0.9)' style={styles.bubblechoice} onPress={this.props.onPress}>
          <Image style={styles.bubblechoice} source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}>
            <View style={[styles.overlay, this.props.selected ? {backgroundColor: 'rgba(80,94,104,0)'} : {}]}>
              <Text style={styles.choicetext}>{this.props.label}</Text>
            </View>
          </Image>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}


class LS1 extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      paleo: false,
      vegan: false,
      vegetarian: false,
    }
  }

  updateChoice(type) {
    let newState = {...this.state};
    newState[type] = !newState[type];
    this.setState(newState);
  }

  SkipLogin() {
    var num = window.height/8.335;
    console.log(num);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.bgImage}>
          <Text style={styles.icontext}>Help us get to know your dietary lifestyle.</Text>

          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'row',justifyContent: 'center',marginTop:-20}}>
              <ToggleButton label='Vegan' onPress={() => { this.updateChoice('vegan') }} selected={this.state.vegan} />
              <ToggleButton label='Paleo' onPress={() => { this.updateChoice('paleo') }} selected={this.state.paleo} />
              <ToggleButton label='Vegetarian' onPress={() => { this.updateChoice('vegetarian') }} selected={this.state.vegetarian} />
            </View>
          </View>

          <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.SkipLogin.bind(this)} underlayColor='transparent'>
            <View style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent', alignItems: 'center', marginBottom: 8}}>
              <Text>skip this step</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>

        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
};

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
  bgImage: {
    flex: 1,
    width: window.width,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  },
  icontext: {
    color: '#5d5d5d',
    fontWeight: '400',
    fontSize: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    paddingLeft: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: window.height/2.2,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  bubblechoice_click: {
    height: window.height/8.335,
    borderRadius: (window.height/8.3350)/2,
    marginRight: 2,
    width: window.height/8.335,
  },
  bubblechoice: {
    height: window.height/8.335,
    borderRadius: (window.height/8.3350)/2,
    marginRight: 2,
    width: window.height/8.335,
  },
  row: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: -30,
  },
  choicetext: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: 'white',
    marginTop: 35,
    fontWeight: '600',
    marginLeft: -18,
    fontSize: 14,
    flex: 1,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  overlay: {
    backgroundColor:'rgba(80,94,104,0.7)',
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    alignItems:'center'
  },

});

module.exports = LS1;

AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => LS1);
```

You can try it out by downloading Exponent to your phone from http://exponentjs.com/ (app store or beta, whichever you prefer) then loading up exp://exp.host/@brentvatne/button-color-exp

Comment: thanks! Yeah finding tutorials hasn't been very easy given the language is so young - I've done a lot of build-an-app tutorials but they don't seem to cover basic things like building a backend for logging in, connecting apis, etc - something where you have a simple full-stack react-native example

Comment: Are there any resources you recommend in particular?

Comment: I just copied the original example and changed the part that was relevant but you are right that the original example and the solution include an invalid rgba value

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way with **TouchableOpacity** and active styles:

```
<TouchableOpacity
style={ this.state.active? styles.btnActive : styles.btn}
onPress={() => this.setState({active: !this.state.active})}>

</TouchableOpacity>
```