# Get backgroundColor of an element onClick in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom-events

I am currently converting a RGB color guessing game I made in vanilla HTML, CSS, and JavaScript into React.

When I click on one of the six divs with the class `coloredSquare`, I want it to grab the backgroundColor of that square and compare it to the rgb color displayed on the screen, coming from the element with the `mainColor` id.

In vanilla JS it is so simple, you just do `this.style.backgroundColor` inside of the `eventListener` but for some reason with React I cannot figure it out. I feel really dumb and I am probably overthinking it and it's actually really simple.

Here's the code:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

class RGBGuesser extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            correctCount: 0,
            displayCorrect: 0,
            colors: "", 
            chosenResult: "",
            chosenCorrect: 0,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.startGame();
    }

    initialGameState = () => {
        this.setState({
            colors: this.displayRandom(6)
        })
    }

    restart = () => {
        this.initialGameState();
        this.setState({
            chosenResult: "",
            chosenCorrect: 0,
            displayCorrect: 0
        })
    }

    pickSquare = () => {
        let colorRan = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.colors.length);
        return this.state.colors[colorRan]
    }

    displayRandom = amountSquares => {
        const colorArr = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < amountSquares; i++){
            colorArr.push(this.chooseRandom());
        }
        return colorArr;
    }

    chooseRandom = () => {
        let rColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        let gColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        let bColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        return `rgb(${rColor}, ${gColor}, ${bColor})`;
    }

    chooseSquare = () => {
      //where i would want to do the logic of clicking the square and comparing it with the rgb color displayed on screen
    }

    startGame = () => {
        this.initialGameState();
        this.restart();
    }

    render(){
        let correctColor = this.pickSquare();
        return(
            <div>
                <h1 id="header">RGB Color Guesser</h1>
                <h3 id="mainColor">{correctColor}</h3>
                <h3 id="result"></h3>
                <h3 id="showCorrect">Number Correct: <span id="correctCount">0</span></h3>
                <button id="startOver" onClick={this.restart}>Start Over</button>
                <div id="colorGrid">
                    <div className="coloredSquare" onClick={this.chooseSquare} style={{backgroundColor: this.state.colors[0]}}></div>
                    <div className="coloredSquare" onClick={this.chooseSquare} style={{backgroundColor: this.state.colors[1]}}></div>
                    <div className="coloredSquare" onClick={this.chooseSquare} style={{backgroundColor: this.state.colors[2]}}></div>
                    <div className="coloredSquare" onClick={this.chooseSquare} style={{backgroundColor: this.state.colors[3]}}></div>
                    <div className="coloredSquare" onClick={this.chooseSquare} style={{backgroundColor: this.state.colors[4]}}></div>
                    <div className="coloredSquare" onClick={this.chooseSquare} style={{backgroundColor: this.state.colors[5]}}></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default RGBGuesser;
```

Comment: What is happening? Is there an error, or am I missing something?

Comment: @1252748 No, there is no errors. It's like I said, I do not know how to go about having it grab the backgroundColor of the square onClick.

Comment: React 16 (and 15.5) doesn't do auto function binding, so `onClick={ this.chooseSquare }` needs to be `onClick={ evt => this.chooseSquare(evt) }` and you may notice this also lets you put that array index in the call to chooseSquare, solving your problem. Your render() code can do with some improvement though, like generating those divs before you return and templating them into the returns statement.

Comment: @ChristianLopez is this just react or react-native? Could you use a touchable highlight? They're bindable to functions.. Here's a question I found that may be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32347605/change-button-color-onpress-toggle-functionality-react-native

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    chooseSquare = (e) => {
      console.log(e.currentTarget.style.background)
    }
```

I think passing the event into your event handler and `currentTarget` \ `target` is what you're missing

Also don't forget to bind your event handler in your constructor!

`constructor() {
// snip
this.chooseSquare = this.chooseSquare.bind(this);
}`

Comment: When I try `console.log(e.currentTarget.style.background)` inside of  chooseSquare it returns an error of " Cannot read property 'currentTarget' of undefined"




EDIT: Wait, nevermind, it doesn't do that anymore. I'll try using this and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Hey, this worked. Thanks a bunch! Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think I need to bind it since I'm using an arrow function. It worked without binding it.

Comment: Yeah, you're right -- you don't need to explicitly bind. I didn't look closely at how you were defining your functions :)